# How to set file permissions on Node.js module install?

Tags: node.js, cross-platform, node-modules, npm-install

I have *private* npm module - `@organisation/module`. My module contains four files - "something.cmd", "something", "something.exe", "index.js".

`index.js`:

```
import path from 'path';
import {exec} from 'child_process';
module.exports = (cb)=>exec(path.join(__dirname, 'something'),  cb);
```

My coworker installed this module (he use OS X) and it failed with error `/Users/coworker/dev/.../something Permission denied`. We fixed it locally by changing `.../something` permissions to `700`, but we need automated way to do this.

Some of our servers run Windows, so we can't run `chmod` Unix command in [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

What are other options?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a script to execute the follwing code in the command line to grant full control of folders in windows `icacls "C:\Folder" /grant Users:F`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
fs.chmodSync(filename, permission)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.